# Could not find class (android)

Tags: android, android-logcat, clipboardmanager

i am trying to run an android application for connecting to a server on my smartphone.
When i try to connect to a sample server saved in the app, i get this on LogCat:

```
Could not find class 'com.appl.app.utils.ClipboardManagerProxy$HCClipboardManager', 
referenced from method com.appl.app.utils.ClipboardManagerProxy.getClipboardManager
```

My device has android 2.3.6 but class ClipboardManager was added in API level 11..could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The highest API level you can use for 2.3.6 is API level 10. See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html). The error can be because of that as you are saying that `ClipboardManager` was added in API level 11. API 11 requires Android 3.0.x .

Comment: ok...now i've tried to do it with a virtual device with android 3.0 but the connection fails...is it a limitation of the emulator?

Comment: with the test server saved in the app...if i install the app on my smartphone the connection works, but if i use the virtual device or my smartphone to run it, it doesn't work!

Comment: Is internet is working on emulator? Are you able to use the browser normally ?

Comment: 08-20 09:35:12.702: E/AndroidRuntime(373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 09:35:12.702: E/AndroidRuntime(373): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: freerdp_new
08-20 09:35:12.702: E/AndroidRuntime(373):  at com.appl.app.services.LibFreeRDP.freerdp_new(Native Method)

Comment: @Butterfly Sorry for the late reply. Can you please post the complete LogCat in question. It would help.